# how to run my application on windows container in azure?

Tags: node.js, windows, azure, docker, powershell-cmdlet

i was just following this [azure article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image) to deploy my application using docker,

The following example creates an App Service plan named myAppServicePlan in the Basic pricing tier (--sku B1) and in a Linux container (`--is-linux`).

```
az appservice plan create --name myAppServicePlan --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku B1 --is-linux
```

how can i create same webapp in windows container.

if i remove `--is-linux` from the command application is not loading , when i hit my application url , it is showing azure default welcome page.

edit : 1

i am actually trying to deploy from dockerhub.

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY server/package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY empty.nwc /usr/src/app/
COPY empty.nwd /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY server/ /usr/src/app/



ENV PORT 80

RUN pwd

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Have u tried these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container, don't know if preview is selectable through the az cli

Comment: Actually trying to deploy my docker image on azure windows

Comment: If the answer helps you solve the issue you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

For the container on Windows, you can create the windows service plan with the command:

```
az appservice plan create --name myAppServicePlan --resource-group myResourceGroup --hyper-v --sku PC2
```

Although the windows service plan is in the preview version. You can get more details about the --hyper-v property from CLI command [`az appservice plan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#optional-parameters). Also with [the SKU of the widnows plan for Container](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/).

Comment: Actually am trying to deploy my docker image on windows container

Comment: So if your image is based on windows, and you can deploy it to the windows plan.

Comment: i am new to docker ,here is my dockerfile , it is running fine on linux but not on windows

```FROM mhart/alpine-node:8

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY server/package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY empty.nwc /usr/src/app/
COPY empty.nwd /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY server/ /usr/src/app/



ENV PORT 80

RUN pwd

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]```

Comment: i have edited my question to see the dockerfile clearly

Comment: unfortunately, the base image alpine-node is Linux system. So you can deploy it on Linux.

Comment: is there any windows node image just like `alpine node`

Comment: can i use this image `stefanscherer/node-windows`

Comment: You can choose an appreciate one from [Windows Container Version Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility).

Comment: i will  , do you have any sample MERN stack boiler plate to deploy it on azure for zip deploy

Comment: What do you mean? The example deploy docker to Azure? Linux or Windows?

Comment: with out docker on windows azure

Comment: I meant regular MERN stack boiler plate to deploy on azure .where we can zip the application and deploy it . I don’t want to go with docker

Comment: Do you have see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs)? Also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#download-the-sample)